# Relative pronoun that and who

Tags: relative-pronouns

I was doing a composition and I had to use the relative pronoun in the following sentences.

> 1- The man _________ you spoke to is deaf.
>
> 2- I gave it to the man ________ I saw there.

Answer of the first sentence was **whom/that** and that of second sentence was only **whom**. To me both of the sentences look the same then why **that** is not used in the second sentence?

Comment: It's hard to say why whoever made the answer key chose those options: in either sentence, an English speaker might use "who", "whom", "that" or no relative word.

Comment: If anybody distinguishes between the two, it's often to use *who(m)* for people and *that* for objects. There is no difference in use between the example sentences in the question. If you can use one in one of the sentences, you can use the same one in the other sentence.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that the word 'whom', while technically correct in a lot of cases, is considered archaic and fussy, and is hardly ever used in any context by native English speakers.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that the choice of relative pronoun in the second sentence hinges on a fine balance that tells us better not to use relative pronoun THAT in subject position in a non defining or non restrictive relative clause

A restrictive clause is an essential part of its sentence; if it were taken out of the sentence, the sentence’s meaning would change. Nonrestrictive clauses are just the opposite. Moreover, some people are squeamish to replace WHO with THAT when referring to people. Grammarly.com endorses the opinion.

https://www.google.com/url?q=https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/english-grammar/relative-pronouns-and-relative-clauses&sa tells us not to use THAT in such situations. In spoken English the usage is quite right but in written English, perhaps, not.